# Undefined method 'center' for nilclass

Tags: ruby

I have a ternary operator which outputs the student count.

```
@students.count < 2 ? puts("Now we have #{@students.count} student").center(75) : puts("Now we have #{@students.count} students").center(75)
```

I had to put the string in brackets after the puts otherwise it would come up as error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
```

However, since I have updated my code to this my method `.center` isn't working and I am receiving this error:

```
`input_students': undefined method `center' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I get around this with the brackets?

Comment: Don't use ternary here, use `if`. Also, you're applying `center` to result of `puts`. Apply it to the string.

Comment: I had an if statement before, but I wanted to refactor.

Comment: Do you think it reads better now?

Comment: "terse one-liners" doesn't equate to "readable code"

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are applying the call to `#center` to the result of `puts` which happens to be `nil`

```
@students.count < 2 ? puts("Now we have #{@students.count} student".center(75)) : puts("Now we have #{@students.count} students".center(75))
```

Note: if student count is 0, then your message reads "Now we have 0 student"

If you want to refactor then you could extract the common parts: centering and outputting

```
message = count < 2 ? 'message 1' : 'message 2'
puts message.center(75)
```

but this will result still result in a long line (depending on the message) so you could use

```
message = if count < 2
            'message 1'
          else
            'message 2'
          end
puts message.center(75)
```

IMHO Code needs to be readable which is not always the same as short. Especially when there is lots of statements crammed into one line.

Answer (score 0):

The Kernel.puts method always return nil.

You probably want to do this instead:

```
puts((@students.count < 2 ? "Now we have #{@students.count} student" : "Now we have #{@students.count} students").center(75))
```

Personally, I'd write something like:

```
message= "Now we have #{@students.count} student"
message << 's' if @students.count > 1
puts(message.center(75))
```

Comment: Your preferred code, while more compact and DRY than the original, is still a maintenance nightmare :)

Comment: Example: what if the template changes to, say, `"Now we have #{@students.count} student in this class"`?

Comment: Example: what if you need to support another language, with wildly different pluralization rules?

Comment: Just something to ponder :)

Comment: If that was something to maintain, I'd use a pluralizer ;)

Comment: That's a bit assertive, mate !